# Relationship between Power Bi tables not working

Tags: powerbi

I have two tables in my report :

1. Stages Table (Column names - Stage Name, Stage Id, Status, etc.)
2. Job Table (Column names - Job Name, Job Id, Stage Id, Stage Name, Job Status, etc.)

One stage has multiple jobs and hence in Job Table, we get the stage Id to which the job belongs.

Now, one of my requirements is if I select a specific Stage Id from Stage Table, I should be able to see all the jobs belonging to that Stage, in the Job Table.

For this, I created a relationship between Stage Id (Stage Table) --> Stage Id (Job Table), basically a one to many relationship as a particular stage Id in stage table will have multiple jobs belonging to that stage.

After creating this relationship and saving all the changes, if I click on any Stage Id from Stage Table, the Job table goes blank. I don't see anything. And this is happening for all the stage Ids from Stage Table.

Note that the data is all correct in both tables. If I apply filter(on dataset level in the data section) in Job Table with a specific Stage Id, I get all the jobs for that Stage Id.

But on the visualization table when I click on stage Id in stage table, the data in Job table just vanishes.
What could be the reason ? Am I missing anything here ?

Comment: In a new PBIX use the (Enter Data) [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-enter-data-directly-into-desktop] feature to test with a simplified model.  Once you've got that working, look to find what's wrong with your other model.

Comment: Can you share a .pbix?